# reference a class with a variable

Tags: actionscript-3, class, variables

I Have this code I have to execute 12 diferent times in my game, and the only thing I need to change is the class name, so I dont have to stay with 12 copies of it (this is just a fraction of it... its a lot to have 12...)

So is there a way to create a variable when I call this function that will change the class "Amarelo" to something else I set before I call it?

```
for (var u: int = 0; u < 3; u++)
{
    var mc: Amarelo = new Amarelo();
    mc.x = larguraTrio + (mc.width + 5) * (u % 3);
    mc.y = alturaTrio + (mc.height + 5) * (Math.floor(u / 3));
    mc.gotoAndStop(Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - u + 1) + u));
    mc.buttonMode = true;
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clique);
    mcExplic.addChild(mc);
    trio.push(mc);
}
```

"var mc: Variable = new Variable();"  ...... ??

I found this looking around and it looks interesting, but I dont know how to format that to my case.... and how to change it b4 the loop... how do I change the "" to be just a word? idk...

```
var Colorcard:Class = getDefinitionByName("flash.display.Sprite") as Class;
var mc:Object = new Colorcard();
```

stumped on this...

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

public class Character
{
    public var charClip:MovieClip();

    public function Character("charName")
    {
        var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName(charName) as Class;
        charClip = new ClassReference();
    }
}
```

Comment: something like...
var mc(variable): (variable) = new (variable)();

Comment: What is the difference between those 12 functions except the name and the frame mcExplic goes to? If there's only a difference in color somewhere, say you have different text color, or whatever, it's the best option to not have several different classes but only one that takes this color as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a lot more simple than I thought

I started declaring a variable for my class

var CARDCOLOR:Class;

than on the function that wants "Yellow" (class name), I use:

CARDCOLOR = Yellow;

it calls my for loop that now adds yellows with this:

mcCard = new CARDCOLOR();  (where mcCard is a movieclip)

Comment: this took away almost 1000 lines of code from my game haha =)